# How to solve SMTP connection problem in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

I have a mail function. And when I start the service it send e-mail from my array. My array include 60 mail. When start the service it send 10-15 mail and after got error like this.

from: The following SMTP error was encountered:

> Unable to send data: QUIT
> quit:

The following SMTP error was encountered:

> Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
> User-Agent: CodeIgniter

```
function sendMail($to,$cc="",$subject,$message,$title="",$attach="",$from="")
{
    $CI = & get_instance();
    $CI->load->library("email");

    $CI->email->clear(TRUE);
    $CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    if($title==""){
        $title="q Group";
    }

    if($from=="") {
        $from="q@q.com.tr";
    }
    $CI->email->from($from, $title);
    if($cc<>"")
        $CI->email->cc($cc);
    $CI->email->subject($subject);

    $CI->email->message($message);
    if($attach<>"")
    {
        $CI->email->attach($attach);
    }
    $mailList = explode(",",$to);
    $sendMailList = "";
    foreach ($mailList as $key=>$item) {
        if (filter_var($item, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $sendMailList .=$item.",";
        }
        else{
            MailLogModel::setLog($item,$subject,0,"Mail Adresi Hatalı");
            if(count($mailList)==1)
                return ["status"=>false,"message"=>"Mail Adresi Hatalı"];
        }
    }
    $sendMail = substr($sendMailList,0,-1);
    $CI->email->to($sendMail);
    if (!  $CI->email->send()){
        MailLogModel::setLog($sendMail,$subject,0,html_entity_decode(imap_utf8($CI->email->print_debugger('headers','subject'))));
        return ["status"=>false,"message"=>$CI->email->print_debugger(array('headers'))];
    }
    else{
        MailLogModel::setLog($sendMail,$subject,1);
        return ["status"=>true];
    }
}
```

My config file is here:

```
$config['protocol']  = "smtp";
$config['SMTPAuth']    = true;
$config['smtp_host'] = "mail.MYSERVICE.com.tr";
$config['smtp_user'] = "";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "";
$config['smtp_port'] = "25";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype']    = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['smtp_timeout']    = 5;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Its quite unusual for a smtp server to use port 25 now! Also unusual for the username and password to be blank!! Check with your email server for what you should be using for port number and uid and pwd

Comment: But I send 10-15 mail after get this error. If SMTP broken why send 15-20 mail?

Comment: Then maybe you have a daily or hourly limit set and you have exceeded it

Comment: I just have a min control. I can send 30 mail  a min. But I use crontab so its not limit or timeout problem. I can see the log mail return false

Comment: IF you are generating emails in a loop, its quite possible you will generate more than 30 in a minute